# Add class to parent div if validation error occurs using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have the following markup for my input fields:

```html
<div class="required">
    <label for="Name">Name <em>*</em></label>           
    <div class="input large">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the jquery validation plugin if an error occurs then it will add a span below the input and also apply a class to the input itself so that the error can be styled. What I also want to do is add a class to the parent div with a class of required. So for example if an error happens it will be `<div class="required error">` and then when fixed `<div class="required valid">` in relation to the classes that are applied to the field and removal of the error span.

How would I do this? I've looked at the documentation site but haven't seen anything to do with adding a class to a parent div.

I've though about doing something like:

```js
if ($('input').hasClass('valid')) {
    $(this).parents('div.required').addClass('valid');

} else if ($('input').hasClass('input-validation-error')) {
    $(this).parents('div.required').addClass('error');
}
```

but how can I run it sequence with the validation? Like when an error takes place or a field becomes valid.

Comment: Keep hoping. I think you will have to override jQuery's validation methods to do what you are trying to do. I assume you are using unobtrusive validation and that only highlights the field itself.

Comment: That's correct but what about some kind of custom jquery that says something like in an input has a class of whatever then make the parent div have a class? And then run this code whenever the class of the input field changes. See OP for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate: add error or validate class to parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431944/jquery-validate-add-error-or-validate-class-to-parent-div)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate - Add Error Class to Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941662/jquery-validate-add-error-class-to-parent-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't played with this at all but you might be able to use [jQuery Validate Hooks](https://gist.github.com/957732)

Answer (score 1):

## Access Validator Settings

The first order of business is to modify the `settings` object on your form's validator. You can do this in any of the following ways:

1. Before the form is loaded for all forms by calling [`jQuery.validator.setDefaults()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/)
2. When initializing the form by passing in options on [`.validate([options])`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)
3. After initialization by locating the validator object on the form with [`$("form").data("validator").settings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764443/1366033)

Since you're using MVC, option #2 is out of the question since [unobtrusive-validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) will automatically initialize the form.  So let's use option 3 going forward - the goal here is just to be able to customize the settings on the form.

## Override Default Behavior

The default methods we'll want to modify are [`highlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) and [`unhighlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight) which will *highlight* invalid fields or revert changes made by the highlight option, respectively.  Here's their default behavior [according to the source code](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/1.16.0/src/core.js#L312):

```js
highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName( element.name ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
    } else {
        $( element ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
    }
},
unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName( element.name ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
    } else {
        $( element ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
    }
}
```

So you have a couple options here as well.

1. Completely replace those functions and write them on your own
2. Wrap those functions and call them like normal but add your own custom code before or after.

#### Option 1 - Replace Wholesale

This route is pretty easy. Just write whatever you want in there.  Maybe seed from the source code, maybe do your own thing.

```js
var valSettings = $("form").data("validator").settings
valSettings.highlight = function(element, errorClass, validClass) { ... }
valSettings.unhighlight = function(element, errorClass, validClass) { ... }
```

#### Option 2 - Wrap Functions

This is less intrusive so probably preferable in most cases.

Since ultimately you will be replacing the value of `valSettings.highlight`, you'll need access to a clean pristine version of the original function.  You can save your own or grab one off the global defaults

```
// original highlight function
var highlightOriginal = $("form").data("validator").settings.highlight;
var highlightDefaults = $.validator.defaults.highlight
```

In terms of wrapping JavaScript functions, there are a couple examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259530/1366033), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326693/1366033), and [here](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/02/03/wrap-javascript-functions.html)).  Here's a parsed down example from one of those, that will help bind `this` context across function calls, preserve the arity of the arguments being passed, and persist the return value:

```js
function wrap(functionToWrap, beforeFunction) {
    return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        beforeFunction.apply(this, args);
        return functionToWrap.apply(this, args);
    };
};
```

Then you'll also have to quickly define whatever additional behavior you want to fire whenever the call is made.  In this case, let's find the closest parent `div` to the element and update it's classes like this:

```
function highlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest("div").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
}
```

**Wrapping It All Up** <sup>(see what I did there)</sup>

```js
$(function () {
  var valSettings = $("form").data("validator").settings
  valSettings.highlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.highlight, highlightDecorator)
  valSettings.unhighlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.unhighlight, unhighlightDecorator)
});

function wrap(functionToWrap, beforeFunction) {
  return function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    beforeFunction.apply(this, args);
    return functionToWrap.apply(this, args);
  };
};

function highlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
}
function unhighlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

So when we combine all of the above functions, it should look something like this:

### Working Demo in Stack Snippets and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p2qpn8kg/)

```js
$(function () {
  var valSettings = $("form").data("validator").settings
 valSettings.highlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.highlight, highlightDecorator)
  valSettings.unhighlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.unhighlight, unhighlightDecorator)
});

function wrap(functionToWrap, beforeFunction) {
  return function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    beforeFunction.apply(this, args);
    return functionToWrap.apply(this, args);
  };
};

function highlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
}
function unhighlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

```css
input.input-validation-error  {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.input-validation-error label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    
<form action="/Person" method="post">
  
  <div class="required">
    <label for="Name">Name <em>*</em></label>           
    <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" 
           data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required."/>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" 
          data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  
</form>
```